# dragonfly : how do i set my language?

Tags: python-dragonfly

I'm using dragon natural speaking with natlink, dragonfly and aena.
It works great in english, but if I load a user profile for another language, I get a weird error.
This error : [Dragonfly IntegerRef getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700823/dragonfly-integerref-getting-a-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable-erro/34702371#34702371)

the good news is it seems a solution exist, but the clear answer to it was not given.
(I don't have enough karma to comment the above issue or to PM the author.)

I guess the solution can be inferred from here :
https://dragonfly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engines.html?highlight=language

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity which language did you have to set?

Natlink engine's [implementation](https://github.com/Danesprite/dragonfly/blob/master/dragonfly/engines/backend_natlink/engine.py#L215) should automatically get the current language from Dragon through the Windows COM interface. Credit goes to Danesprite for this portion of answer.

```
                     0x0c09: ("en", "AustralianEnglish"),
                     0xf00a: ("es", "CastilianSpanish"),
                     0x0413: ("nl", "Dutch"),
                     0x0009: ("en", "English"),
                     0x040c: ("fr", "French"),
                     0x0407: ("de", "German"),
                     0xf009: ("en", "IndianEnglish"),
                     0x0410: ("it", "Italian"),
                     0x0411: ("jp", "Japanese"),
                     0xf40a: ("es", "LatinAmericanSpanish"),
                     0x0416: ("pt", "Portuguese"),
                     0xf409: ("en", "SingaporeanEnglish"),
                     0x040a: ("es", "Spanish"),
                     0x0809: ("en", "UKEnglish"), 
                     0x0409: ("en", "USEnglish"),
```

Note older versions of Dragon may support fewer languages.
[Supported languages for Dragon NaturallySpeaking 15 products](https://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/6280/kw/Dragon%20NaturallySpeaking%20languages%20supported/related/1)

Retail Editions:

Dragon Home 15

```
English
German
```

Dragon Professional Individual 15

```
Dutch
English
French
German
Italian
Spanish
```

Dragon Legal Individual 15

```
Australian English
English
German
New Zealand
```

Dragon Professional Group Single User 15

```
Dutch
English
French
German
Italian
```

Dragon Legal Group Single User 15

```
English
German
```

Enterprise Editions:

Dragon Professional Group 15

```
Dutch
English
French
German
Italian
```

Dragon Legal Group 15

```
Australian English
English
German
New Zealand
```

Dragon Law Enforcement Group 15

```
English
```